# TD width value not working with fixed layout

Tags: html, css

I have set table layout as fixed and width as 100%

```css
.rect {
      background: #f5f8f8;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: calc(100% - 600px);
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="rect">
    <tr>
      <td class="cir-wrap">
        <img src="https://zepplin-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/email-images/not-started.png"
      </td>
      <td class="task-info">name</td>
      <td class="task-time ">1.3&nbsp;h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="task-note">
        <span>Note: </span>
        <span>Please search your related skills</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but the task note is not having width 100%, can someone tell me the reason

Comment: how can `width: calc(100% - 600px);` become *width 100%*, is that setting your intention?

Answer (score 0):

you did not set the width to 100% but to `100% - 600px` and you missed to close the image tag. fixing these two things works for me...

```css
.rect {
            background: #f5f8f8;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="rect">
    <tr>
      <td class="cir-wrap">
        <img src="https://zepplin-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/email-images/not-started.png"/>
      </td>
      <td class="task-info">name</td>
      <td class="task-time ">1.3&nbsp;h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="task-note">
        <span>Note: </span>
        <span>Please search your related skills</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```